# Separating words with comma python

Tags: python

I want to grab a word by using a comma as the end of the word indicator using python and also remove the extra quotation marks and white spaces. Also one more thing I also want to make every letter of the word lowercase, then loop to the next word in the text file.

For Example:

```
Text File:
"Test Word", "The Test", "Word Two", "Word Four", "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"
```

I am willing to make further clarifications, any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `just ask me if you don't understand a part of it.` Most of us would be interested to see what you tried?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a "do my homework for me" site. Try something, and if you have a *specific problem* with your implementation, feel free to ask about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't have any code to reference, I'll give a high level explanation of what I would do:

Use `str.split()` with a comma as your delimiter to break up the string into an array of strings.

Since you need to remove both whitespace and quotes, I would use regular expressions via a replace function, `re.sub`, to adapt these new strings.  It would look something like: `'\"|\s'`, replace with `""`.  You can use `str.lower()` to convert all characters to lower case. Hope that helps.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper No problem.  In the future, if you don't want to be downvoted to death, post what you have tried already.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper Since you're new, you should take the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). Good luck!